# Why doesn't this code convert emoticons into emojis?

Tags: python, emoji

I am trying to make a program that converts emoticons in text to emojis. Specifically the goal is convert every ':)' and ':(' into a slightly smiling emoji and slightly frowning emoji, respectively. I have decided to do this by using the replace function.

---

```
def main():

# ask user for input
# save input into variable 'string'
    string = input()

# call function convert() and pass 'string' into it
    convert(string)

# print the newly modified string that has an emoji instead of an emoticon if a :( or :) is used
    print(string)

def convert(nstring):

# replacing each instance of a :) or :( with the equivalent emoji
    nstring= nstring.replace(":)", "").replace(":(", "")
    print(nstring)
    
# return the new string back to main()
    return nstring

main()
```

---

Input:
Hi
:)

Desired output:

Hi

Hi

Actual output:

Hi

Hi :)

I have tried to use the encode and decode functions to no avail. It seems I am able to successfully print out the nstring with all emoticons converted to emojis. The barrier I am facing is returning this string to main with all the emojis intact. I have no idea why the function is not letting me return it this way. Perhaps I need to convert the string into byte-form, then return the bytes, then decode those bytes?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to make the string equal to the return of the function, so the string would be your input and it would not be converted.

```
def main():
    string = input()
    string = convert(string)
    print(string)

def convert(nstring):
    nstring= nstring.replace(":)", "").replace(":(", "")
    print(nstring)
    return nstring

main()
```